# Featherlight with google street view images

Tags: javascript, google-street-view, featherlight.js

I am trying to fetch Google Street View images and display them in a light box using featherlight. The images are defined dynamically based on which map icon a user selects.

My image displays without issue but the lightbox freezes for a second and then returns a page of random characters as if the image has been attempted to read as text.

An example of my code is as follows:

```
let streetView_imgURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" +
    props.Latitude + "," + props.Longitude + "&key=MYKEY";

document.getElementById("selectedSchool").innerHTML = (props ? 
"<div class='imgbox'>" +
    "<img style='width:100%;' data-featherlight='" + streetView_imgURL + "'src='"
    + streetView_imgURL + "'>"
```

Comment: A working example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue well, try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/markovica/1njee7ah/2/

```
<style>.gsv-screenshot {display: none}</style>    
<a href=".gsv-screenshot" class="" data-featherlight>Click Me</a>
<div class="lightbox gsv-screenshot">
    <i class="featherlight-close fa fa-close"></i>
    <img style='width:100%;' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=44.8165107,20.4603276">
</div>
```

find a way to generate items this way. It doesn't seem to have issues.